# Particle stutters the first time it is spawned (UE4)

Tags: unreal-engine4, particles, emitter

The first time I spawn a particle, it seems to stutter and ends up with a weird square around it (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsGEb.png)). The problem does not occur when spawning it fom the second time and onwards.

Even if I close the game window and execute it again, the problem does not happen again. It only returns if I completely close and reopen the Unreal Engine.

To spawn the particle, I am using the ["Spawn Emmiter at Location"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFSpP.png) node. Also I am using Unreal 4.25.0.

After running the profiler, I can see that there is a [spike in the Game Thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YKBE.png) in the exact frame when the problem occurs. It indicates that the [spike is in the "self" event name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHhLO.png), but I don't know what that means.

Does anyone know what may be causing this and how to fix it? Any tips on how to further investigate?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by spawning the particle system offscreen, at the beginning of the level. By doing that, when I actually want to spawn the particle for real, it will already be the second time and work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but I suggest you to take a look at [PSO Caching](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/PSOCaching/)